# adding table to ruby on rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm working on Ruby on rails and I am taking a poll- in this case it is a guest book with a poll- 
right now the migration file in the DB folder :

```
class CreateGuests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :guests do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.string :doctor
      t.string :captain
      t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Any how I want to alter the database so that captain and doctor are foreign keys pointing to tables with those names

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want easily by using the references keyword in place of the column datatype and adding a foreign key.

```
class CreateGuests < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :guests do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.references :doctor, index: true
      t.references :captain, index: true
      t.text :comment

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :guests, :doctors
    add_foreign_key :guests, :captains
  end
end
```

Comment: Copy, paste, then rake db:migrate, just like every tutorial tells you.

Comment: if you already run migration then run  rake db:rollback then paste above code then run  rake db:migrate